# Clear Cell Script Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm looking to run some script to clear the contents of a cell in column E (i.e. E3) when a cell in column I (i.e. I3) is edited ("Complete" is selected from drop down list). I found this script on another forum but am new to script editing and am not sure how to make it fit my needs (and if I can). Any and all help would be much appreciated.

---

```
// when a cell in column A (A:A) is changed, clear the corresponding cell in column B
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart === 1) { 
    e.range.offset(0,1).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a cell in column I is edited with the value "Complete, you want to clear the contents of the cell on the same row in Column E.

Note some of the differences between this answer and your script:

- each of the watched values are defined (column and value) as is the target column. While this is NOT essential, it does makes it easier to manage.
- there is a single `IF` statement in which the conditions are described.

  - each of the conditions is separated by `&&` ("AND")
- The target cell doesn't need to be defined as an offset; it can just be defined as the same row, and a given column.

  - `sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, clearCol).clearContent()`

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  // identify the range and values to watch and clear
  var watchCol=9; // Column I
  var watchValue = "Complete";
  var clearCol = 5; // Column E
  // 

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the column = "+e.range.columnStart+", and the value = "+e.value)
  if (e.range.columnStart === watchCol && e.value === watchValue) { 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the conditions were met");   
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, clearCol).clearContent()
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz

I see that we've defined the row, however, I was wanting this to work for all rows (i.e. for any row where column I contains "Complete", the contents in Column E will be cleared). Will your script address this?

I ran the above script and but nothing is happening when I change I2 to "Complete". Do you have any troubleshooting advice for a noob? Thanks!!

Comment: FYI: "i.e. I3" <> "e.g. I3". _I was wanting this to work for all rows_ Yes, I did wonder about that; it is a simple change and is a good reason why one uses  the "row,column" format of `getRange()`.

Comment: So, this now works on any row at all. The IF statement tests only for the Column number (9) and the change value ("Complete"). and the row number for the cell to be cleared =  `e.range.rowStart` = the row that was edited. As I said, a fairly simple and (I hope) logical change.